Can Statamic invoke a controller before rendering a Page Builder block?
I'm exploring some options to build some custom functionality in Statamic. My preference would be to use the normal page builder to associate a custom block with a particular page. But - the custom block needs to do some preprocessing before rendering itself.
Is it possible to invoke a controller before Statamic renders a particular block? I don't want to create a normal Laravel route and controller for this, as it must operate within the context of the page builder functionality, and the users must be able to manage surrounding blocks on that page in the normal fashion.
Or, is there a better approach I've not considered yet?
The documentation details how to create a controller and render a Statamic view, but that's insufficient for the requirements.

You could maybe look at writing a custom tag to perform whatever kind of custom logic you need? https://statamic.dev/extending/tags

I believe a View Model is what you're looking for. "View Models give you a chance to manipulate or set data in PHP right before everything is passed into your view, parsed, and then rendered." https://statamic.dev/view-models
